# Java: NullPointerException when trying to update SWT Label from a different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I understand, from reading here in SO and from other sources online ([this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/eclipse-cookbook/0596007108/ch08s12.html) for example), that you cannot access SWT objects from a different thread.
Indeed, when I try to do this:

Class Menu:

```
public class Menu {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("Main thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getId()); // prints 1

        final Display display=new Display();
        final Shell shell=new Shell(display);
        Label l=new Label(shell, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
        l.setText("Some label");
        l.pack();

        SecondThread second_thread=new SecondThread(l);
        Thread t=new Thread(second_thread);
        t.start();

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Class SecondThread:

```
public class SecondThread implements Runnable {

    private Label label;
    public SecondThread(Label l) {
        label=l;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Second thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getId()); // prints 8

        for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000); // waiting three seconds...
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            label.setText("i is: "+i); // SWTException is thrown here
        }
    }
}
```

It throws SWTException:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.setText(Unknown Source)
    at tst.SecondThread.run(SecondThread.java:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The solution suggested here, and in other sources online, is to use Display's `asyncExec()` method, which:

> Causes the run() method of the runnable to be invoked by the
>   user-interface thread at the next reasonable opportunity. The caller
>   of this method continues to run in parallel, and is not notified when
>   the runnable has completed. Specifying null as the runnable simply
>   wakes the user-interface thread when run.

So I tried to replace:

```
SecondThread second_thread=new SecondThread(l);
Thread t=new Thread(second_thread);
t.start();
```

With:

```
SecondThread second_thread=new SecondThread(l);
display.asyncExec(second_thread);
```

But as it turns out, this not really creates new thread of execution, as the output suggests:

```
Main thread: 1
Second thread: 1
```

Consequently, the `Thread.sleep(3000)` invocation makes the GUI window unresponsive...

So I tried a different approach:

Menu:

```
public class Menu {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("Main thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getId()); // prints 1

        final Display display=new Display();
        final Shell shell=new Shell(display);
        Label l=new Label(shell, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
        l.setText("Some label");
        l.pack();

        SecondThread second_thread=new SecondThread(l);
        Thread t=new Thread(second_thread);
        t.start();

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

SecondThread:

```
public class SecondThread implements Runnable {

    private Label label;
    public SecondThread(Label l) {
        label=l;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Second thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getId()); // prints 8

        for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000); // waiting three seconds...
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            updateLabel("i is: "+i);
        }
    }

    private void updateLabel(final String string) {

        Display display=Display.getCurrent(); // display is not null...

        display.asyncExec(new Runnable() { // throws NullPointerException... 

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("test");
                label.setText(string);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this throws NullPointerException:

```
Main thread: 1
Second thread: 8
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tst.SecondThread.updateLabel(SecondThread.java:33)
    at tst.SecondThread.run(SecondThread.java:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And I have no idea why...
Does anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: The runnable in `updateLabel` has another issue: you shoud check if the `label` still exists with `label.isDisposed()` before accessing it as it might have been disposed meanwhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SecondThread` is not the user interface thread so `Display.getCurrent()` will return `null` since only the user interface thread has a current display.

Use `Display.getDefault()` to get the display from any thread.

Comment: Great! It works!!! I could have sworn I checked `display` for null...
Anyway, thanks so much.